# Load Fragment View without displaying it to user

Tags: android, fragment, screenshot

The structure of my module is like there is one activity[Activity] which holds four fragments[Frag1..Frag4] and each fragment has 2 more fragments[frag_a,frag_b] attached to it.

```
                                      Activity

           Frag1            Frag2                 Frag3             Frag4

       frag_a frag_b    frag_a frag_b         frag_a frag_b     frag_a frag_b
```

Imagine Frag1..Frag4 each one as one unit. User selects say Unit1, Unit3. I need to take screenshots of frag_a,frag_b from unit1(Frag1) and screenshots of frag_a,frag_b from Unit3(Frag3). Remember, unit1 and unit3 are users choice. User is only aware of this selection part and he is not concerned with all that goes with screenshots and other things. None of the fragments are already attached by the time user gives his choice.

So my requirement is that I need to load the fragment and take screenshot but the fragment should not be displayed to user. Imagine I have to do this for 4 fragments. So, I am thinking of running a loop to load fragment, take screenshot, store bitmap and the loop continues for next unit and so on.

I tried many approaches but couldn't find a solution. Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
fm.beginTransaction().hide(somefrag).commit();
```